# Is it good to declare a local variable in the middle level of your code?

Tags: java, coding-style

while reading the book "clean code" I came across the following instruction:

"Local variables
should be declared just above their first usage and should have a small vertical scope. We
don’t want local variables declared hundreds of lines distant from their usages."

see the following example:

```
 public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        String name = "Robert";
        String country = "iiiii";
        int age = 21;
        String hobby = "Soccer";
        System.out.println("my name is "+name+"I'm "+age+" and I'm from "+country);
        /*

             * 
             * a lot of code here
             * 
             * */
            System.out.println("my hobby is: " + hobby);

        }
    }
```

Here the variable hobby is a throw stone from its usage , so I want to make sure if it is clean to write like the code bellow?, because I often see local variables declared in the top level of the function :

```
/*the previous code here*/
String hobby = "Soccer";
System.out.println("my hobby is: " + hobby);
```

Comment: I find it more readable. If your method is long, it's better to declare variables when you need them, so that others who read your code don't become crazy searching for variables. But that's just my opinion ;)

Comment: Trust that instruction in the book :)

Comment: @BackSlash yes you're right, nice opinion .thanks

Comment: Well,the quote you included answered your question. So what is it you don;t understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually recommended to declare a variable in least possible scope. So declare it where u use it. 
It just makes your code little cluttered.

Comment: indeed; it's at the same time useful and cluttered

Answer (score 5):

What the book is saying is correct as a general rule when we are talking about local variables.

The point it is that code tends to be a lot more readable if you keep the declaration and the usage of a variable close together.  If they are far apart, you are likely to find yourself scanning backward through many lines to find the declaration.  This breaks your concentration.

(Modern IDEs have clever ways to show you a variable's type, or to go to its declaration.  However, it is still easier if you can just see the declaration and usage on the same "page".)

Having said that, this is a matter of personal preference to some degree.  Some people like to "declare variables at the top", because some old-school programming languages do not allow declarations and other statements to be interspersed.